# Are there any major browsers that do not preserve insertion order in a JavaScript Object?

Tags: javascript, object, cross-browser

Can I depend on the following code alerting `b` before `a`?

```
var x = {}
x['b'] = 1
x['a'] = 0
for(var i in x) {
    alert(i)
}
```

Comment: I don't know, but my gut says you shouldn't have to. If you need to depend on the order, use numeric indexes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the V8 JavaScript engine used in Google Chrome, a similar discussion took place:

http://code.google.com/p/v8/issues/detail?id=164

It's better to not rely on undocumented features. And it you're using numbers as keys, it certainly goes wrong.

For example this breaks in some browsers:

```
var x = {}
x['b'] = 1
x['2'] = 20
x['a'] = 0
x['1'] = 10
for(var i in x) {
    alert(x[i])
}
```

BTW it's `alert(x[i])`.

Comment: If the OP wants to know the key, then it's actually alert(i). +1 for link

Comment: Ah, the OP just updated his/her code. http://stackoverflow.com/posts/6139759/revisions

Comment: Note that Carakan (in Opera 10.50+) and Chakra (IE9+) use the same ordering (unit32-named properties in numeric order, then everything else in insertion order).

Comment: I actually want to know both. I would have preferred a preserved order so I use less code, but I will avoid this method.

Answer (score 7):

> Are there any major browsers that do not preserve insertion order in a JavaScript Object?

At least one major browser did until recently (I think the V8 engine didn't preserve order).

> Can I depend on the following code alerting b before a?

No. The spec says that there is no order.